# Escaping HTML in HAML

Tags: escaping, haml

Another stupid HAML question.  I need to escape HTML in plain strings, without "=":

```
%p
  This paragraph has <n> lines.
```

Whatever I do (like prepending "&"), it still renders as

```
This paragraph has  lines.
```

I am using Rails 3.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can escape HTML with `:escaped` filter.

> Works the same as plain, but HTML-escapes the text before placing it in the document.

Example:

```
%p
  :escaped
    This paragraph has <n> lines.
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the HAML documentation here: http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#escaping_html

There might be a better way of doing it, but this does work:

```
& This paragraph has #{"<n>"} lines
```

That will generate

```
This paragraph has &lt;n&gt; lines
```

Comment: I am aware of this.  Enclosing anything in `#{}` will force running it through Ruby, which I don't believe is necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

`This paragraph has &lt;n&gt; lines`

Comment: One of the points of using a template language is to avoid writing entities by hand, so I cannot accept this.